# Whats the meaning of the phrase "Всякую хню"

Tags: узус

I'm not sure if the meaning is offensive or not. Somebody wrote me in a game chat and there's nothing meaningful in google translate for "ХНЮ" while "ВСЯКУЮ" translated for "ANY".

Comment: It's shortened word meaning bulls*t. As you understand this is filthy language; it doesn't necessarily mean it was offensive (although it could).

Comment: I would add that I never heard such contraction _pronounced_. It is indeed very similar to 'bulls\*t' but written without any '\*' (because it's clear anyway).

Comment: Right way to write this phrase is: "Всякую хуйню" ("уй" are missed).

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan or всякую херню

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is shortened word which means "garbage", "nonsense" or "rubbish" with the strongest grade to express "how much is it bad" (in all meanings, but mostly in figurative, like when someone wants to express how wrong things are told to him).

The translator didn't find anything because original word lacks 2 letters, "y" and "й" (I will not write the word neither its correct translation here as I don't think it's appropriate; correct me if I'm wrong). In the context given by you I think it was used as something to express

> you shouldn't tell *those lies / wrong ideas / wrong assumptions / bad things* to me

regarding something what was spoken about.

Comment: `original word lacks 2 letters, "y" and "й"` Or maybe "е"+"р" which is essentially the same thing )

Comment: @Matt correct, for some reason I thought only about one word, (even couldn't write it correctly from the first time).

Comment: regarding something what was spoken about: I asked a friend why she has changed her avatar and she said I'm tired of men telling me "Всякую хню". I asked for translation but she left it to me.

Comment: @Xaqron well, in this case it was meant as "you asked something very inappropriate / even stupid that you had to understood by yourself".

Answer (score 2):

Well, I will take the risk, because filthy language is a part of language. [Here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%83%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8F) is a lot of info about that word.

And [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82) is info about russian filthy language in general.

Good luck!